# Finding index using cellfun in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to find an index using cellfun using matlab and I got this error:

```
??? Error using ==> cellfun
Input #3 expected to be a cell array, was double instead.

Error in ==> auc at 17
index = cellfun(@strcmp,y,labels(test));
```

Code:

```
indices = crossvalind('kfold',labels,10);
confusionMatrix = cell(1,1);
errorMat = zeros(1,10);
for i = 1:10
test = (indices==i);
train = ~test;
% Train the TreeBagger (Decision Forest).
model = TreeBagger(20,data,labels, 'Method', 'classification'); 
y = model.predict(data(test,:));
index = cellfun(@strcmp,y,labels(test));
errorMat(i) = sum(index)/length(y);
confusionMatrix{i} = confusionmat(labels(test),y);
end
```

Comment: What is the content of `y` and `labels(test)`? `labels` is probably a cell array of strings?

Comment: y = 

    '1'
    '1'
    '1'
    '1'
    '1'
    '2'
    '2'
    '2'
    '2'
    '2'

Comment: labels(test)

ans =

     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     2
     2
     2
     2
     2

Comment: labels is a Nx1 matrix with 100 observations

Comment: The inputs into `cellfun` all need to be cell arrays.

Comment: What is your code supposed to do? For this input I have no Idea what "finding an index" should do.

Comment: This code is complete gibberish.  Please explain **what your code is supposed to be doing**.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I should have converted labels(test) from numeric to cell

```
index = cellfun(@strcmp,y,labels(test));
```

becomes:

```
index = cellfun(@strcmp,y,num2cell(labels(test)));
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `arrayfun` instead... which takes in an **array**, rather than a cell?  Also, `strcmp` can operate on cells of strings.  You can convert both inputs into cells and call `strcmp` once.  Using `cellfun` here is a crappy way to write code (no offence).

Comment: Assuming your data looks really like the data in your comment, this code is nonsense. It will always return `false(size(y))`